# why can't I use multibinding with the IsEnabled property of the button?

Tags: wpf, button, binding, multibinding, isenabled

I am trying to set the IsEnabled property of a button using multibinding, because this property depends on three variables.

If I would set the content propery, I could use this code:

```
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="629,49,0,0" Name="btnMyButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiValueConverter}">
                            <Binding ElementName="MyElement"/>
                            <Binding />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I try to use this code:

```
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="629,49,0,0" Name="btnMyButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
                    <Button.IsEnabled>
                       <?????
```

But in this case, although the Button.IsEnabled is avaliable, in the next line I can't find the Multibinding keyword, so I can't use multibinding with the IsEnabled property.

why? Is there any way to set the IsEnabled property with a multivalue converter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax should be the exact same as what you have for `Button.Content` - just replace `"Content"` with `"IsEnabled"`.

```
<Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiValueConverter}">
        <Binding ... />
        <Binding ... />
        <Binding ... />
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.IsEnabled>
```

It might not auto-complete for you because the `IsEnabled` property expects a boolean value, not a `MultiBinding` object, but it shouldn't give you any errors, and will compile and execute just fine.

(It auto-completes for `Button.Content` because the `Content` property is of type `object`, which includes a `MultiBinding` object)

Comment: Finally I compile with Button.Content, then change content by IsEnabled, compiled and then works. Thanks.

Comment: @Rachel Only problem here is that `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`does not trigger Binding. I tried putting `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` in each `Binding` element and also in the `MultiBinding` element, but it doesn't update. I have to change the focus for it to work